# Observable objects replace on the html view

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wrote a code for uploading posts and comments from VK. I use direct API requests (not a library). Angular project. The problem is that the html posts are displayed one by one and replace each other as they load, but I want them to be added to the bottom

```
  public getPosts(): Observable<PostView[]> {
    return this.vkApi.getShortPostsInGroup('https://vk.com/stackoverflow', this.offset).pipe(
      tap((data: RootPostResponse) => this.offset = data.response == null ? 0 : data.response.offset),
      map<RootPostResponse, PostView[]>((data: RootPostResponse): PostView[] => {
        let normPosts: PostView[] = [];
        let posts = data.response.posts;
        for (let index = 0; index < posts.length; index++) {
          let post = posts[index];
          for (let i = 0; i < post.id.length; i++) {
            normPosts.push({
              id: post.id[i],
              date: new Date(post.date[i]),
              owner_id: post.owner_id[i],
              text: post.text[i],
              comments: []
            })
          }
        }
        return normPosts;
      }))
  };

  public getComments(): Observable<any> {
    return this.getPosts().pipe(
      mergeMap((posts: PostView[]) =>
        posts.map((post:PostView) =>
          this.vkApi.getCommentsInPost(post.owner_id, post.id, 0)
            .pipe(
              map((rootCommentResponse: RootCommentsResponse) => {
                return rootCommentResponse.response.comments?.map((comment: Comment) =>
                  <CommentView>this.comment2CommentView(comment, post)
                );
              }),
              map((x:CommentView[])=>{post.comments=x; return post}),
            )
        ),
      ),
      concatAll()
    );
  }
  posts$: Observable<any> = this.getPosts();
  comments$:Observable<Post[]> = this.getComments();
```

and html view

```
<pre>{{((comments$ | async ) || undefined) | json }}</pre>
```

Also I can't understand, what type have getComments(), so I wrote any

I tried using different rxjs operators instead of mergeMap, changed the behavior of only toArray() at the end, but it waits for all observers and only then outputs the result, and I want the result to be added as it loads